# How do I select only top <li> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is a html. I don't care it's valid or not, I just want to query "title to select" from it using jQuery and nothing more.

```
<div class="my class1213">
    <h3> just title, no selection</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>title to select</li>
        <li>title to select
            <ul>
                <li>nonono</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>title to select
           <ul>
             <li>
                 <ul>
                     <li>no selection</li>
                 </ul>
             </li>                 
          </ul>     
        </li>    
    </ul>    

</div>​​​​
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.my ul li:first');
```

Should be enough

Alternatives:

```
$('.my ul li:eq(0)');

$('.my ul li:nth-child(1)');
```

Edit based on undefined's comment:

You could use his solution, or something like:

```
$('.my ul li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text === 'title to select';
});
```

Comment: @SeToY Should work when your using jquery and not as a pure css selector

Comment: @undefined Ah ok, i made an update with another possible solution.

Comment: nth-child only from IE9, not below. I've had to deal with this myself yesterday. See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @SeToY jQuery's selector engine (Sizzle) implicitly handles it for you. Try this fiddle in ie7-mode: http://jsfiddle.net/WdHYy/

Answer (score 2):

you can either use the CSS selector for it, or use a [jQuery traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Traversing&redirect=no) function.

Option a:

```
$('.class1213 ul li:first-child')
// selects only the first li child of ul
```

Option b:

```
$('.class1213 ul li').first()
// first selects all li's, then only uses the first element found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.my > ul > li:first-child');
```